# Python ETree.find not finding with complex path

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml element that looks like this

```xml
<PI Name="MonitoredVariable">
    <Reference Object="SomeName" />
</PI>
<PI Name = "Other Properties" />
<PI Name = "Other Properties" />
<PI Name = "Other Properties" />
```

I want to grab the reference element

When I try to grab the reference element with

```py
ref = elem.find("./PI[@Name='MonitoredVariable']/Reference")
```

ref ends up as None.

When I try to grab the reference element with

```py
if superref := elem.find("./PI[@Name='MonitoredVariable']"):
    ref = superref.find('Reference')
```

ref ends up as the correct value. The second set of code is harder to follow and probably slower so I would much prefer to figure out why the first set of code isn't working.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there an example we can run? For me, the `root.find("./PI[@Name='MonitoredVariable']/Reference")` is running correctly.

Comment: I get the same experience as Andrej, wrapping all the `PI` in a root element of some sort `./PI[@Name='MonitoredVariable']/Reference` will find the element expected, in every version of python from 3.7 to 3.11. Without an actual test / repro script, it's not possible to know what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, please edit, what you like to catch and how looks your root tag?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_s = """<root><PI Name="MonitoredVariable">
    <Reference Object="SomeName" />
</PI>
<PI Name = "Other Properties" />
<PI Name = "Other Properties" />
<PI Name = "Other Properties" /></root>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_s)

ref = tree.find(".//PI/Reference[@Object]")
print(ref.attrib['Object'])
```

Output:

```
SomeName
```